# I want save data in sqlite Database, My Query not working in webpage But same code wroking fine in Django Shell

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

I am trying to add some data via Views.py but it not working but the same code working in django shell.

[image: Django Shell Execution]

My Code :

```
username = request.POST['username']
bp = request.POST['bp']
bs = request.POST['bs']
height = request.POST['height']
weight = request.POST['weight']
temp = request.POST['temp']
datasaved = PatTest(Patient= Patient.objects.get(username=str(username)), BS=int(bs), BP=int(bp), PatHeight=float(height), PatientWeight=float(weight), BMI=BMICal(height, weight), TEMPA=int(temp))
            print("Test")
datasaved.save()
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Looks like the `request.POST` dictionary does not contain all the necessary data.

Comment: @ruddra it's not generating any error

Comment: i did try with all necessary data but not working

Comment: Try `your_var = request.POST.get('whateverdata', False) print(your_var)`. If it shows `False` there's a problem with your request or form.

Comment: @Reez0 i did try with but same problem  https://i.imgur.com/K7jM7Ch.png

Comment: **Don't** use  unvalidated & unsanitized daa from`request.POST` for this - **use a django ModelForm instead**, it will take care of validating your data, creating/updating your model if ok, and returning a well-built, easily usable error report else (and they also know how to render themselves - whole or parts - so it makes your template code cleaner and easier to maintain).

Comment: Finally Solved This Question. The Problem was `BMI=BMICal(height, weight)` . I just use `BMICal(float(height), float(weight))`

Because it was float Value in Models class so i just mentioned in it

Answer (score 0):

Finally Solved This Question. The Problem was `BMI=BMICal(height, weight)` . I just use `BMICal(float(height), float(weight))`

Because it was float Value in Models class so i just mentioned in it

```
username = request.POST['username']
            bp = request.POST['bp']
            bs = request.POST['bs']
            height = request.POST['height']
            weight = request.POST['weight']
            tempsd = request.POST['temp']
            print(Patient.objects.get(username=str(username)).PatID)
            datasaved = PatTest(Patient= Patient.objects.get(username=str(username)), BS=int(bs), BP=int(bp), PatHeight=float(height), PatientWeight=float(weight), BMI=BMICal(float(height), float(weight)), TEMPA=int(tempsd))
            datasaved.save()
```